# Detect Close all tabs/Close current tab on navigator

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox-addon, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to detect when a tab is being closed.

```html
<script language="javascript">
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0) || (window.event.altKey == true)) {
   var xmlhttp;
   var date = new Date();
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
   else {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     .......
     }
    );
```

With onbeforeunload  I can detect that event, and checking coordinates from event I can detect when user closes tab by click on tab cross.

Is there any way to detect when user clicks on modal window of navigator? In that case, coordinates position does not work

[image]

Comment: I am using IE11, but maybe solutions with other browsers may help. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what is your end goal, but you should be aware that there are situations that no "window is about to be closed" event will be fired.
For example, when the browser is crashed or tab is forced closed using Chrome's task manager, etc.

Comment: My goal is detect that event for clear data from session

Comment: First off, forget about windows -- a user agent isn't necessarily GUI with windows. Even Internet Explorer 11 can be operated with voice -- the mouse pointer may not even move. In any case you can't detect mouse position for the system window -- there is no API for that, *thankfully*. The event you are looking for -- the one you handle to do clean-up of your "sessions" -- has the type `"unload"` or `"pagehide"`. Both are documented as part of HTML 5 at http://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#events-2. Goog luck.

Comment: I suggest you to prompt the user by using onbeforeunload event. You can check the returned value. If the user want to close than you can clear the data. Ref: https://dev.to/chromiumdev/sure-you-want-to-leavebrowser-beforeunload-event-4eg5 and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-browser-or-tab-closing-in-javascript/

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Do you think that's preferable to handling "unload" or "pagehide" types of events? If you do, why?

Comment: It will just like a confirmation with the user. To use it or not, it is totally depends on op's requirement.